# Вызов функции внутри preg_replace (регулярные выражения)

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть код

```
        $exp = \filter_input(\INPUT_POST, "exp");
        if (isset($exp) && $exp != "") {
            \preg_match_all("#%(.*?)%#si", $exp, $matches);
    
            foreach ($matches[1] as $item) {
                $exp_new = str_replace($item, strtoupper($item), $exp); // все работает
                echo $exp_new, "<br>"; // первая строка вывода
            }

           
            $tmp = preg_replace("#%(.*?)%#si", strtoupper("$1"),$exp); // не работает strtoupper
            echo $tmp; // вторая строка вывода
        }
```

Ввод

> %vvvv%

Вывод

> %VVVV%
>
> vvvv

Почему в `preg_replace` не работает `strtoupper("$1")` ?

Если написать

`$tmp = preg_replace("#%(.*?)%#si", "$1"."dd",$exp);`

то вывод будет

> vvvvdd

То есть все будет как надо. Почему php игнорирует функцию (и только ее, так как % % обрезаются) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно воспользоваться функцией [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
$exp = "%var first% and %var second%";
$tmp = preg_replace_callback("#%(.*?)%#si", function($matches) {
    return "%" . strtoupper($matches[1]) . "%";
    },$exp); 
echo $tmp; // => %VAR FIRST% and %VAR SECOND%
```

[Пример использования](http://ideone.com/UTe7r9)

Answer (score 0):

А где написано, что PHP должен это поддерживать?
Оборачивай `strtoupper` вокруг `preg_replece`, тогда. Или уж в переменную и делай с ней, что хочешь.